# JavaScript filter function filtering out zeros in array

Tags: javascript, type-coercion

Please see code below. it runs but it does not return the correct value.

For an input: [0,4,0] the output should be [0,0,0]

Comment: Why output should be `[0,0,0]` ? Please elaborate more.

Comment: You haven't put any code.

Answer (score 0):

Because **0 is a Falsy value** in Javascript.

And **`.filter`** function will filter out all the falsy values like **0, , false.**

> use some other logic in **`.filter`** method.

```js
let arr = [0, 4, 0].filter((number) => number >= 0);

console.log(arr); // [0,4,0]

arr = [0, 4, 0].filter((number) => number);

console.log(arr); //[4]

arr = [0, 4, 0].filter((number) => number > 0);

console.log(arr); //[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Take the length of the input array
2. Create a new array with those many 0s using [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).

The code should look like this: `let outputArray = new Array(inputArray.length).fill(0)`